# Properly connect PostgreSQL database to flask app with blueprints and without using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to find the right way to connect a PostgreSQL database to my flaks app that is separated in blueprints without using SQLalchemy. I have found similar answers, but none are in my situation. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by not using SQLalchemy? Does it mean you do not want to use the library at all or you don't want to use the SQLAlchemy models?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. I really don't like the model system. I don't have any technical limitations, I could use it.

Comment: If you don't like the model system then you can easily use the structure I have given below!

Answer (score 4):

I will do something like this:

The structure of the application will look like this:

```
├── application                    # hosts the application     
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── blueprint1                 
│   ├── blueprint2
├── application.py                 # contains the actual python code that will import the app
└── config.py
```

Now inside your **init**.py, you can create the database connection like this

```
from flask import Flask
import psycopg2

db_connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=suppliers user=postgres password=postgres")


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    application = Flask(__name__)
    application.config.from_object(config_class)

    # register blueprints here

    from application.blueprint1 import bp as blueprint1_bl

    application.register_blueprint(main_blueprint, url_prefix="/")

    from application.blueprint2 import bp as blueprint2_bl

    application.register_blueprint(
        blueprint2_bl, url_prefix="/bl2"
    )

    return application
```

And now let's say you have to access it from blueprint1 and blueprint1 is a separate directory. Then I will have a directory structure for each blueprint as below:

```
├── blueprint1 /
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── static/blueprint1/                 
|   └── templates/blueprint1/                 
|   └── routes.py
```

Now from your routes.py file you can access the database connection as below:

```
from application import db_connection
from application.blueprint1 import bp

@bp.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def bl1_page():
    """It renders bl1 Page."""
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from mobile"

    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")
    mobile_records = cursor.fetchall()

    print("Print each row and it's columns values")
    for row in mobile_records:
        print("Id = ", row[0], )
        print("Model = ", row[1])
        print("Price  = ", row[2], "\n")
    return render_template(
        "blueprint1/blueprint1.html"
    )
```

And if you don't know how **init**.py file inside the blueprint will look like, it would look something like this

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint(
    "blueprint1",
    __name__,
    template_folder="templates",
    static_folder="static",
    static_url_path="/blueprint1/static",
)

from application.blueprint1 import routes
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thefcraft/flask_postgresql

`# pip install flask-pgsql --user`

```
from flask_postgresql import PostgreSQL
db = PostgreSQL(hostname=hostname, port=port, database=database, username=username, password=password)

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.Integer, array=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Test({self.id}, {self.data})" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if RESET:
        db.create_all() # with app.app_context(): db.create_all() will also work
    p = Test(data = [21, 24])
    db.session.add(p)
    db.session.commit()
    Test.query.get(id=1).data #-> [21, 24]
```

Comment: Hi ThefCraft, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks